# React to a Message Previously Sent in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is a pretty basic one, but I'm wondering how I could possibly have any user send a message, then have someone type something (e.g. !react EMOJI_NAME) and have it react to the message sent by the random user and THEN delete the message "!react EMOJI_NAME". I already have a system that can send any custom emoji, animated or not, but I do not have a way to react to a specific message sent by a different user (which is why I can't just search for the first message in a channel or identify a message sent by the author) Anyone got any tips for how to identify the second message sent in a channel? Any help is appreciated :)

**Note:** This code below won't work because it will react to the message "!react EMOJI_NAME" and then proceed to delete the exact same message. Thanks for reading!

```
case 'react':
          var { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
          var emojis = client.emojis.cache.filter(e => e.name.toLowerCase() === args.join(' ').toLowerCase());

            var content = '';

            emojis.forEach(emoji => {
              content = `${content} ${emoji}`;
            });

            message.react(content)
              .then(function () {
                message.delete()
              })
              .catch(function () {
                var errorEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setColor('#ff0000')
                  .setDescription(`<:error:784747315960479754> There was an error finding that emoji`);
                message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
              });
            break;
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `fetchMessages()`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's in an `async` function

```js
message.delete(); // delete the message first

const [target] = await channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 1 }); // get first message in the channel

const emojis = client.emojis.cache.filter(e => e.name.toLowerCase() === args.join(' ').toLowerCase()); // get all emojis

emojis.forEach(emoji => { // loop through every emoji
  await target.react(emoji); // react to the message with said emoji
});
```